# Javascript update and ignore undefined fields in destination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I am looking to essentially update a large javascript object. However various tools in the front end add unnecessary fields that should be ignored when updating the object. I am working with angular but open to using lodash/underscore if necessary. I just want to be able to update the existing object without adding the extra fields that are injected when it is placed in the UI.

```
var ob1 = {
    attr1: 'stuff',
    attr2: 'stuff'
};

var ob2 = {
    attr1: 'changedstuff',
    attr2: 'stuff',
    uiCrap: 'junk'
};

update(ob1, ob2);
// should result in 
// ob1 = { attr1: 'changedstuff', attr2: 'stuff };
```

Does anyone out there know if there is any built in angular/javascript functionality for this?

Comment: With lodash: `_.extend(ob1, _.pick(ob2,[Object.keys(ob1)]))`

Comment: this does what i want, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [extend()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) function:

```
var ob = _.extend(ob1, _.pick(ob2, _.keys(ob1)));
```

Comment: this will copy unwanted fields from object two.

Comment: @pipedreams2 . i have modified the expression which would only select the attributes part of `ob1`

Comment: Is the `ob` variable really necessary? It's just a reference to `ob1`.

Comment: @AdamBoduch  It's obviously not required. :) There was a console statement below that which removed by mistake.